# Returning all rows from database in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to fetch the data from database with compare of some fields using get_where but every time it's returning data even where condition does not satisfied...

My Code is:

```
function check_sec_token()
{
    $sec_token=$this->session->userdata('sec_token');
    $email_id=$this->session->userdata('email_id');
    $query=$this->db->get_where($this->_registration,array('sec_token'=>$sec_token,'email_id'=>$email_id));
    $rows=$query->num_rows();
    return $query->result();
    if($rows<1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

if `$sec_token` and `$email_id` is null then it returns all rows from the database..i also tried

```
function check_sec_token()
{
    $sec_token=$this->session->userdata('sec_token');
    $email_id=$this->session->userdata('email_id');
    $query=$this->db->get_where($this->_registration,array('sec_token'=>$sec_token,'email_id'=>$email_id));
    $rows=$query->num_rows();
    return $this->db->last_query();
    if($rows<1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

it's showing query

```
Select * from user_reg where sec_token=0 and email_id=0
```

Comment: So you are asking that the conditions are not working....right??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    ...

    if ($sec_token == NULL && $email_id == NULL)
    {
        $query=$this->db->get($this->_registration);
    }
    else
    {
        $query=$this->db->get_where($this->_registration,array('sec_token'=>$sec_token,'email_id'=>$email_id));
    }

    ...
```

Comment: but dear my question is that....it should not return all records if conditions are not true.... if the session variable have null value then why it's adding 0..

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

```
return $query->result();
```

This piece of code stops running the rest of your code! and your condition on row count is not considered!

you can do this instead:

```
$query=$this->db->get_where($this->_registration,array('sec_token'=>$sec_token,'email_id'=>$email_id));
$rows=$query->num_rows();
if($rows<1)
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: ya i know..i just use it for testing...is it showing all result...but actually i need number of rows...... it should not return any record if condition is not satisfied..... **it's returning all records even condition is not true**

Answer (score 0):

Here if $sec_token and $email_id are null or "0" then query  you will fetch all records.It will give all rows because when "where condition not satisfied then it fetch all records" try it.Also check your session is start or not and your values is set or not in it properly.